# Uncaught In promise Dom Exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever I call the play method on an audio I get the Uncaught (in promise) Dom Exception error here is a screenshot,
[image]

and here is what i did

```
function NotificationComment(cat,place) {
  clearInterval(notify);
  var url = $("#notification").val();
  var val = $("#" + cat).val();
  $.get(url, {type: cat, prev: val}, function (data) {
    arrayData = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#'+place).html('&nbsp; ' + arrayData.count + ' &nbsp;');
    $("#"+cat).val(arrayData.count);
    if(arrayData.sound==1) {
      notify = setInterval(function () {
        $("#audio")[0].play();
        NotificationComment('G', 'commentNot');
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      notify = setInterval(function () {
        NotificationComment('G', 'commentNot');
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
}
if($("#auth").val()==1) {
  notify = setInterval(function () {
    NotificationComment('G', 'commentNot');
  }, 2000);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: wrap this `$("#audio")[0].play();` with a `try/catch` to see if you get something useful for debugging

Comment: @quirimmo i got same response as in the screenshot

Comment: sorry I just watched your code better. I think the issue is in the `get` method. Try to chain a `.fail` method that will catch errors in your HTTP GET request

Comment: the get method is working perfectly its when i call the .play i get the error

Comment: My guess is that the browser does not allow automatic playing of sounds, most browsers don’t afaik. Add a try/catch around the play statement, see if the exception‘s error type is NotAllowedError. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play

Answer (score 1):

I ended Up finding a Solution thanks to @patrick Hund, was able to understand the fact that most browser restricts autoplay of sounds and videos which leads to a promise exception, I solved this by creating a button which is hidden and is clicked whenever a new notification comes in here is my code
**Js**

```
 function NotificationComment(cat,place){
       clearInterval(notify);
       var url = $("#notification").val();
       var val = $("#"+cat).val();
       $.get(url,{type:cat,prev:val},function (data) {
              arrayData = JSON.parse(data);
              $('#'+place).html('&nbsp; '+arrayData.count+' &nbsp;');
              $("#"+cat).val(arrayData.count);
              if(arrayData.sound==1){
                  $("#player")[0].click();
                  notify = setInterval(function () {
                      NotificationComment('G','commentNot');
                  }, 2000);

              }else{
                  notify = setInterval(function () {
                      NotificationComment('G','commentNot');
                  }, 2000);
              }

       });
   }
if($("#auth").val()==1) {
        notify = setInterval(function () {
            NotificationComment('G','commentNot');
        }, 2000);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<audio id="myAudio">
        <source  src="{{url('assets2/audio/definite.mp3')}}">
    </audio>
    <button id="player" onclick="play()">Play</button>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById('myAudio');
        function play() {
            x.play();
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks Guys

Comment: I’m surprised it’s so easy to work around the autoplay permission restriction.  Are sure your trick works in all target browsers

Answer (score 0):

Also these are also possible solutions, Go to [chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy](http://chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy) for chrome users and activate the autoplay settings there or use

```
audio=new Audio('audiosource');
audio.play();
```

in javascript;